# Why do people believe that if Putin ceases to be Russian president, the Russo-Ukraine war will cease?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, vladimir-putin

It seems like quite a lot of people think that the current war in Ukraine is entirely down to Putin, and if Putin dies / is assassinated / is replaced in a coup etc, then the war will end. Examples:

> WASHINGTON -- South Carolina Sen. Lindsey Graham is facing intense pushback from all corners of Washington after calling for the Russian people to end the Ukraine war by assassinating President Vladimir Putin.

[Source](https://www.ctvnews.ca/world/white-house-disavows-graham-s-call-for-putin-assassination-1.5806232)

> The only way out of this crisis is to make Putin’s failure in Ukraine so disastrous for Russia and its genuine interests that his own elite will have no choice but to remove him.

[Source](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2022/mar/03/vladimir-putin-ukraine-war-chechnya)

Some protests say "[Stop Putin](https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-polytics/2219892-stop-putins-war-in-ukraine-40-rally-held-in-riga-photos-video.html)" instead of "Stop Russia".

The implication is that 1) the current war is entirely because of Putin, and Putin only; and 2) if Putin loses power somehow then the war will cease because his successor will not continue the war.

How do we know that Russian foreign policy will change (and by how much) should Putin lose power?

Related: [Why do news articles often refer to the leader as opposed to the country?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63516/why-do-news-articles-often-refer-to-the-leader-as-opposed-to-the-country) However, the current anti-Putin (but not anti-Russia) news seems more precisely targeted on Putin than the answer to that question would indicate.

Comment: This question is effectively asking to quantify the exact impact of Putin on the fate of Russia. This might be too speculative in the end. A potential successor of Putin could be even more extreme than him or much less. "How do we know that Russian foreign policy will change!" As with many things we don't. Nobody can predict the future. The logic is probably something like: Putin  = evil, no Putin = less evil. How much less is currently unknown.

Comment: Upvoted, but with regards to Lindsey Graham's remarks those seem counterproductive if one assumes (I do) that Putin is the main decider of this war.  Calling for his assassination is against norms of diplomacy, makes the US appear extremist by extension and is unlikely to convince *Putin* to behave more morallly.  LG is a senior enough politician that he really should know better - I suspect this has more to do with putting distance between himself and Trump (Genius Putin!) for *domestic* political reasons without *obviously* dissing Trump.  Quite, quite, contemptible.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yeah, Lindsey Graham is very much alone on calling for this in public. Even [real psychos like Representative Marjorie Taylor Greene](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/2022/03/lindsey-graham-russians-should-assassinate-putin.html) think that him saying this is "dangerous & unhinged".

Comment: "The implication is that (...)" - the listed implications somehow miss the point IMHO. It's not really possible to tell what would be without Putin. However, an important purpose of saying "Stop Putin" instead of "Stop Russia" is not so much that it's Putin and no-one else that needs to be opposed. It is that it's *not* "Russia" (as a country, or its people) that the protest is directed at. After all, two typical moves of propaganda are 1) the claim that protests against country X are not because X is guilty of a certain wrongdoing, but because "the others" irrationally want to put down ...

Comment: ... X no matter what. And 2), the claim that protests against any actions chosen by the political establishment of a country X are actually meant as a direct attack against the country X and its people as a whole. In order to not unintentionally feed into that propaganda, some critics of the Russian invasion of Ukraine try to make sure their protest cannot be mistaken as a general attack on Russians, their culture, or their country in general.

Comment: "The implication is that 1) the current war is entirely because of Putin, and Putin only; and 2) if Putin loses power somehow then the war will cease because his successor will not continue the war." Not quite, the implication that is removing Putin is a necessary condition to ending the war, not necessarily a sufficient condition by itself.

Comment: Which people believe? The question seems to be refering only to people in the West.

Comment: @Trilarion the question doesn't ask what *will* happen if putin was removed, it asks why some *think* a specific course of action will have a specific result.  Actually telling people what is going to happen is out of scope, explaining why it's believed a given policy or action will have a given result to inform decisions made about such a policy is totally in scope.  Though I think it should still be said that no one realistically thinks Putin is gong to be disposed.  This is more about rhetoric then an actual call for, or belief in the viability, of a removal.

Comment: Graham also [more recently] says the US should bomb Iran otherwise the Hothis won't stop. Like with many similar statements about untried scenarios, there's no way of knowing for sure any of this, of course. Also "Why do people believe ..." and "How do we know that ..." are slightly different Qs. A lot of people believe the last US elections were "stolen" for instance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think this question answers itself.

1. Opposition to the war in Ukraine — and the sanctions placed on
   prominent players and the nation as a whole — is the main reason
   anyone in Russia would want to risk an assassination or coup
   attempt. Putin has been in power a long time (and secured power for
   the foreseeable future) without any such efforts; the only thing
   that's changed is the war.
2. Anyone who successfully wrests power from Putin is going to face
   internal struggles and the need to consolidate his new position
   of power. In that kind of transition a foreign war would work
   against interest. The new leader would want to stabilize the
   international situation quickly in order to focus on internal
   problems.

It's extremely unlikely (and I suspect impossible) that any new leader would be *more* hawkish and expansionist than Putin. Can you imagine a group staging a coup because they think Putin is not warlike enough?

Comment: See how hard it is to work out the military commanders for the operation in Ukraine. Everything leads back to Putin rather than a group or collective of personalities dictating. I recall a transcript from Defense Minister Shoigu meeting with Putin, ends in ".. exercises that were planned and launched on your instruction..."

Comment: Stepping out of the war w/o reaching its goals, effectively losing it, won't stabilize anything inside the country. I'm pretty sure it would have the opposite effect and it would  be a political (and probably literal) suicide.

Comment: @ixSci A potential new leader could announce that stopping the war will a) stop the continued loss of life of Russian soldiers and b) end the Western sanctions and so start on a path to rebuilding the economy. This would hopefully be more attractive than continueing the war with an unknown outcome and an unclear longterm perspective even if it is won.

Comment: @quarague the western sanctions will not end, at least not fast enough to prevent political suicide of said leader.

Comment: *Opposition to the war in Ukraine ... is the main reason anyone in Russia would want to risk an assassination or coup attempt* Perhaps the would-be assassin could be trying to impress someone? (as happened with [Ronald Reagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attempted_assassination_of_Ronald_Reagan))

Comment: @alamar The promise to end them might come very quickly. It is in the interest of the West to support a leader that would stop the war. I would assume that a credible announcement from Russian leadership to pull out of Ukraine would lead to promise of lifting (some) sanctions within hours.

Comment: @quarague doing anything to please the West for them to lift the sanctions will be received as a weakness and nothing else. We already had Yeltsin which tried to be friends with the West and people remember how it ended.

Comment: If Putin announces that, it's possible, though we all understand that promises may not turn into actions by both sides. But for Putin's weaker, uncertain successor it's not that easy, he may be asked to disengage first and unconditionally.

Comment: *Can you imagine a group staging a coup because they think Putin is not warlike enough?* Maybe not a coup (although I am positive there are counterexamples in history), but I can imagine a new leader being even more warlike if Ukrainian operatives assassinate Putin.

Comment: @Allure That's presumably why no one thinks that a Ukrainian (or western) secret operation to assassinate Putin is a good idea. If you notice the news you're quoting in the question, they are all calls for the *Russians* to remove Putin.

Comment: There’s historical precedence. In the beginning of 1917, the revolution deposed the tsar, but continued the war. That lasted only a few months before the well known October Revolution deposed the new government and installed an even newer which eventually did end the war.

Comment: @Holger However keep in mind, that the new communistic government of Russia was even more hostile to the West then the previous one.

Comment: Going by the number of wars of choice started per decade, I certainly can think of more hawkish leaders.

Comment: @Holger [precedent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precedent), not [precedence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precedence).

Comment: @phoog too late to edit the comment… But thanks for the correction.

Comment: @quarague Russian leader suported by the West will not stay a leader long enough, the most russian see the West as an enemy no meter if they suport Putin or not.

Comment: "Can you imagine a group staging a coup because they think Putin is not warlike enough?" While the answer, at least at the moment, more likely be no, this doesn´t mean the group will stay in power or even gain it. Best examples are the previous coups 1917 and 1991, where the group which starte the coup was not able to keep power and was replaced by exact opposite one.

Comment: I would add that Russia is suffering heavy loses with little forceable benefit in the war currently.  Even if they do manage to gain land it will come with continued heavy sanctions that likely will cost them more then the land they gained benefits them, and gaining land is far from guaranteed.  The only reason the war continues is it would look too bad on Putin to admit defeat.  If someone replaces Putin and paints the war as an example of Putin's terrible policy's then stopping Putin's 'pointless war' need not make them look weak and comes with lots of positives for the country.

Comment: @dsollen What happens to Crimea and Donbass then? Losing a sizeable chunk of your country without a fight could not be framed as a victory even by Ukraine at its weakest point.

Comment: @alamar Russian forces leave and Russia respects the international consensus on those regions. It is easily framed as a "victory" if, instead of focusing on the "loss" of territory the new leader presents the decision as "there is no longer a chance that you / your brother / your son will die in an unjustified and pointless war".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146666/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-why-do-people-believe-that-if-putin-ceases-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "Can you imagine a group staging a coup because they think Putin is not warlike enough?" Yes, as actual events show.

Comment: @convert: you missed the point of a rhetorical question

Comment: I know it was a rhetorical question, but the answer doesn´t feat.

Comment: "Can you imagine a group staging a coup because they think Putin is not warlike enough?" I can. Just watching Russian TV, there's plenty of nutters wanting to nuke Ukraine or even London. And from a few statements by the "systemic opposition" they try to one-up each other on who's the most hardline on the war. The [so called] "Liberal Democrats" were always war nutters. The communists openly say they want to re-establish the USSR etc.

Answer (score 24):

Because the war that Russia is waging against Ukraine is a war of choice.  There were no imperatives leading to the war.  There was no immediate threat.  There was no attack being waged against the Russian Federation.  **The decision to start the war was driven solely by the desire to step in a certain historical direction by Putin.**  Regardless of whether he was right or wrong (and he was wrong) in evaluating the historical trends, there was no immediate cause of action other than Putin's opinion.

Can a different leader have the same opinion?  Sure.  But even Putin wouldn't start the war today if he knew how it would turn out.  But, unlike Putin, **a new leader (even one who shares all of Putin's historical views) would not be burdened with all the responsibilities arising out of having made the decision to start on a path to what turned to be a disaster.**

Comment: One 'madman' cannot dictate the policy of a nation unless there are both masses and elites going along with it. Blaming it all on Putin is too simple.

Comment: @o.m. Sure, but Putin probably had quite a strong impact on the fate of Russia lately.

Comment: @o.m. do you mean in principle or in this particular case?  Because there are many examples in history of individuals maintaining control by the threat of sheer terror hanging even over his immediate circle.  I am not saying that's happening exactly, but that's just a matter of degree.  I think after Putin fired Medvedev as Prime Minister, everyone else became a figurehead.  Medvedev was a former President.  If he wasn't safe, no one would be.

Comment: Can you cite sources for some of the assertions in your answer?

Comment: The problem is that Putin/Russia has formally annexed [what's internationally recognized as] Ukrainian land, so they're in a bit of constitutional pickle in Russia to just pack up an leave now. Anyone just plain doing that can be formally charged with treason etc. in Russia. So it would take some more revolutionary change than merely a personnel change in leadership to untangle this, on the Russian side. It's true that in  Russia laws often change at the whim of the leader, so there's that possibility. If United Russia were selected more for sycophantism than something else...

Comment: @Fizz they did exactly that in Kherson. They left (I think within weeks) of making it their territory constitutionally. And then I think it just took a Putin decree to remove it from the list of the new territories. Laws are mostly rubber stamped there. They are not a meaningful constraint on government actions. They are only a constraint on citizens' actions, and even then only as a guidance rather than as "the law". I think Putin had Russia invade Crimea within months of having a law passed which made it illegal for him to do that.

Comment: "it just took a Putin decree to remove it from the list of the new territories". Link?

Comment: @Fizz I don't remember obviously.  I was quoting from memory.  You can google as well as I can, but trying to understand the Russian constitution is a fool's errand because no one believes it has any weight, so few try to analyze it.  Presumably, a Presidential decree is the last step in annexation.  So maybe he modified the decree to not claim the territories lost between when the amendment process started and when the decree was issued.

Comment: @Fizz sorry, I realize that my last comment is probably not very satisfying, but it's been almost a year since these events.  And I just have anything other than my memory of reading about it at the time.

Answer (score 12):

Because, whenever there is a dictator in power, they create a vacuum in the hierarchy of intellect. Most of the time, it is created automatically. Other times, it is created deliberately. Therefore, when a dictator dies or is removed by revolutions, the system of the country takes a long time to regroup and to start functioning in its full power.

This is observed times and again throughout history.

For instance, the USSR plunged into chaos on multiple occasions because of this.

The recent examples are Iraq and Libya.

Comment: A county with nuclear weapons becoming an other Iraq or Libya, would be really dengerous.

Answer (score 6):

You've really presented three cases: Putin dies, the Russian people assassinate Putin, and the elite remove him from power. The first case, in which Putin merely dies, is the least conducive to the ending of the war. There's little indication that there was a push from the Russian elite for the war, so once Putin is removed, whoever takes power may decide to withdraw, but that's not as strong as in the other cases.

An assassination of Putin by Russian people would require either someone to be very lucky, or to have broad support. The assassination would both be an effect of broad support, and evidence of that support, emboldening further dissent. It could easily trigger a revolution and/or civil war, and if the anti-Putin side wins that conflict, they would end the war in Ukraine.

If Putin is removed by the elites, it would signal a turn from Putin's policies, of which the war is the most prominent. It, similar to an assassination, would signal the ascendancy of anti-Putin factions, and may cause people to jump on the anti-Putin bandwagon, as that side would then appear to by the side winning. Generally speaking, coups succeed once everyone thinks they will succeed, and assassinating Putin would be a strong sign that the coup will succeed. Anyone thinking of not joining the coup would have to wonder, "If they can assassinate Putin, why wouldn't they be able to assassinate me?" It would also provide cover for a withdraw, by purging the Putin loyalists, blaming them for it, and claiming to have been against the war from the beginning.

Comment: But the assasination could eventualy have the opposite efect, example assasination of Sadat.

Answer (score 0):

During the history of the Soviet Union, change of the leader quite often resulted significant changes in the country. This is also when the leader simply died from the old age (J.
Stalin, L.Brezhnev).

It is not very clear, why. Theoretically kings and dictators should not matter much in the history and be replaceable, if not him then somebody else. It must be strong social forces behind every dictator: *he though he is leading them, actually they just pushed him in front of themselves*.

But this view contradicts the experience, or maybe death of the current leader initiates changes that are long mature.

Comment: I downvoted because of the last paragraph - no political theory says kings and dictators (leader) doesn't matter. In fact, the whole Ukranian crisis could be termed as an attempt by the west and Russia to prop up their own puppet leader in Ukraine.

Comment: I received my formal educational in Soviet Union but as I remember it was always emphasis on what personalities do not matter. Russia cannot put a puppet leader in the Ukraine "as is". They must support the leader with they troops, economic pressure, abunndant propaganda and things the like for this to work

Comment: *it was always emphasis on what personalities do not matter.* - I am sorry, I did not understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Well I agree to the extent that Putin has gone a bit mad, and prighozin and other connected Russians probably know that it's a tragic wasteful war and of no benefit to Russia.

Comment: Which exactly change of the leader of the Soviet Union resulted significant changes in the country?

Comment: L. Brezhnew, for instance. All era has gone.  J Stalin I think also.

Answer (score -3):

***Why do people think that if Putin ceases to be Russian president, the Russo-Ukraine war will cease ?***

By people, you surely mean people in Western Europe and the Western Hemisphere.

And I often ask myself the same question when I read supposedly educated people, people old enough to remember WW2 and even past students of modern history making the same foolish speculation on TV.

Every dog will bark at its own doorstep, the saying goes. And the Russian dog has so much more vigilance than most given its appalling losses (~ 30 million people) in World War 2. It may be "politically incorrect" to say so these days but Russian people in general - not just Putin or whoever preceded/succeeds him - will object to having a NATO country in a neighboring state, moreover one that, though distinct in culture and language, has such long ties with Russia. They will also be mindful of Hitler's viewing the plains of the Ukraine as merely a *lebensraum* for the Greater Germany.

That is the *realpolitik* of the current situation. And it will have to be considered in depth before we are likely to have a permanent cessation of war and full withdrawal by Russia. Sanctions will hurt Russian people but not deter their determination to defend what they feel as the threats around them.

It is a great pity that someone of international stature was not invited to mediate a solution acceptable to this situation before it boiled over some years ago. Many political cruxes involving conflicting rights have been resolved around concord wordings respecting the rights of all concerned but in the shared context of the common right of all: to simply live.

So I doubt if ordinary people in the West think removing Putin will really remove the war. But people in Western media like journalists and commentators are simply afraid to express an officially unpopular - and admittedly very tough - truth. I wish [Fisky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Fisk) was still around.

Comment: We don't really know what Russians are thinking with any good error. Maybe they are fully behind Putin, maybe not at all. Time will tell. Would WW2 have been the same if Hitler would have (somehow) died in 1939?

Comment: @Trilarion "the same" - no, but "have been" - yes

Comment: @Trilarion Difficult on the one hand dictators cultivate a cult of personality so their presence or absence can make an irrational difference in terms of public approval. Though at the same time a dictator is never just one person there's a whole apparatus often to the point where the actual figurehead is more of a puppet than a leader. So it can make a difference or they could just "go on vacation" or have irregular pre-scripted addresses.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution *We don't really know what Russians are thinking with any good error. Maybe they are fully behind Putin, maybe not at all. Time will tell. Would WW2 have been the same if Hitler would have (somehow) died in 1939?* So you think that the impact of 30 million dead in WW2 on the consciousness of post-war Russian people will be detachedly put aside on the basis of the type of statistical observation that would be made by Martians ? This is the sort of dream-think hardly even being made by the State Department hawks, let alone by people in Russia.

Answer (score -6):

This belief is based on historical experience. Only in the last century Russia got defeated 2 times after the leader of the country was overthrown. So if it was posible to defeat Russia 2 times this way, why should it not work again. There are even more examples from an earlier history of Russia, but the closest example is 1917 when Russia got defeated in World War 1 after the tsar was overthrown and killed.

Some people also might think if Putin dies there wil be something like [Second Miracle of the House of Brandenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracle_of_the_House_of_Brandenburg) when the Empress Elizabeth of Russia had died and her nephew Peter signed peace treaty.

Comment: i donno where you read this hisfairy tail, but in 1917 Russia wasn't defeated in WW1 and in 1918 too. There was a separate peace treaty in Brest-Litovsk, not a lose. Communists just declined the imperialistic's war targets and had out pf the war. And Nikolay wasn't overthrown - he renounced the throne by self, and not communists help him to put off the crown, but liberals did.

Comment: @άνθρωπος I know that Nikolay was forced in Februar 1917 by liberals to resign, which was defenetly a coup. Brest-Litovsk was not a ceasefire, but a recognition of defeat as large territories had to be surrendered to Germany.

Comment: Rus was not defeated in the WW1, in was inner conflict. Treaty of separate peace was not cos defeated. Ukraine that was alienated in 1918 was joined in 1919 back, but some territories had not joined back, because Rus Empire was not exist. But SU had joined lots of another territories in short time after.